# How does spring-boot @ConditionalOnClass work?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

How exactly does the `@ConditionalOnClass` annotation work?

My goal is to load a specific bean only if the `jar` providing this class is included in the classpath.

I thought the I could annotate a `@Bean` with `@ConditionalOnClass(MyService.class)` and declaring the dependency in maven as optional:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>de.my</groupId>
    <artifactId>my-framework<artifactId>
    <optional>true</optional>
</dependency>

@Bean
@ConditionalOnClass(MyService.class)
public MyConditionalBean statistics() {
    return new MyConditionalBean();
}
```

Now, anyone having `my-framework` as dependency should get that bean automatically wired. But anyone not having the dependency should skip it.

But when I start the app, I get the following error:

```
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: de.MyService.class
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1702) ~[catalina.jar:7.0.50]
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1547) ~[catalina.jar:7.0.50]
```

So I'm probably doing something wrong. How can I then create the bean conditional on the dependency jars and the classes contained in the classpath?

From the spring docs:

> The classes that must be present. Since this annotation parsed by
>   loading class bytecode it is safe to specify classes here that may
>   ultimately not be on the classpath.

But the error states different...

Answer (score 27, accepted):

Good catch!

You can use on `@Bean` method level, but in that case you have to specify your class as a String literal:

```
@Bean
@ConditionalOnClass(name ="de.MyService")
public MyConditionalBean statistics() {
    return new MyConditionalBean();
}
```

I don't remeber already "why", but it is from an existing code of Spring Boot sources.

Comment: If you put it in a top level class I would except the class to be pulled in at class loading time. That is when using the class. Using it as a String literal prevents this.

Comment: As a note if it's declared at the class level it doesn't have to be a String literal.  Go figure. https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/api/org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/condition/ConditionalOnClass.html#value--