# How does spring boot check for classes that don't exist on the classpath using conditionalonclass annotation?

Tags: spring, spring-boot, java-bytecode-asm

Somewhere it is mentioned that asm is used behind the scenes. If anyone can point me where it is done in the framework or an example would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How does spring-boot @ConditionalOnClass work?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25789907/how-does-spring-boot-conditionalonclass-work)

Comment: Not really, I looked at that question already. That was talking about using spring boot but my question is how it works internally.

Comment: It's less complex than that. 

Essentially they just try to load the class, and can be traced back to this method.https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/blob/master/spring-boot-project/spring-boot-autoconfigure/src/main/java/org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/condition/FilteringSpringBootCondition.java#L135 Checkout the `OnConditionalClass` which extends the `FilteringSpringBootCondition`.

Answer (score 0):

Imagine the following case
`dependencyA` contains `dependencyB`

and your `POM` looks like the following

```
   <dependency>
        <groupId>com.company.name</groupId>
        <artifactId>dependencyA</artifactId>
        <version>1.1.1</version>
        <exclusions>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>com.company.name</groupId>
                <artifactId>dependencyB</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
        </exclusions>
    </dependency>
```

so you added `dependencyA` excluding `dependencyB` to your project in the other word the `dependencyB` is not in your `classPath` --> so if you used `@ConditionOnClass(com.company.name.dependencyB.myService.class)` it wont execute the code